# Will my question be closed as a duplicate if there is a similar question asked on other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

Suppose I ask a question on SO or Meta SO. The question isn’t a duplicate of any question on SO or Meta SO. However, if my question is similar to a question asked on another site on the Stack Exchange network, will my question be closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to close a question as a duplicate of something on another site:

[image: The duplicate question must exist on SITE]

Additionally, on non-meta sites, the duplicate question to close against must either be asked by the same user or have an upvoted or accepted answer, otherwise only a mod can use it as a duplicate target.

Some users may close vote (with a custom reason) if you've been cross posting.